# how to implement mapbox on custom page renderer in xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mapbox

I am trying to implement the mapbox xamarin.android sdk on a custom page renderer to consume it from a xamarin forms application. So far i have been able to create the custom renderer with a text label and consume it. it looks like this:

[//image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0D4V9.png)

this is my pageRenderer class:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof(MapPage), typeof(MapPageRenderer))]
namespace mapetor.Droid
{
public class MapPageRenderer : PageRenderer, TextureView.ISurfaceTextureListener
{
   global::Android.Views.View view;
   MapView map;

   protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e){
       base.OnElementChanged(e);

       if (e.OldElement != null || Element == null)
       {
           return;
       }
       try
       {
           // load some android xaml
           Task.Run(() =>
           {
               SetupUserInterface();
           }).ContinueWith((rslt) =>
           {
               AddView(view);
               Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { map.OnCreate(null); });  
           });
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
       }
   }

   private async void SetupUserInterface()
   {
       var activity = this.Context as Activity;
       view = activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.mapLayout, this, false);

       Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async() =>
       {
           // instanciando el mapa
           map = FindViewById<MapView>(Resource.Id.mapView);
           map.StyleUrl = Mapbox.Constants.Style.Emerald;
           var mapboxMap = await map.GetMapAsync();
           var position = new CameraPosition.Builder()
           .Target(new LatLng(41.885, -87.679))
           .Zoom(11)
           .Build();
           mapboxMap.AnimateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.NewCameraPosition(position), 2500);
       });
   }


   protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
   {
       base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);

       var msw = MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(r - l, MeasureSpecMode.Exactly);
       var msh = MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(b - t, MeasureSpecMode.Exactly);

       view.Measure(msw, msh);
       view.Layout(0, 0, r - l, b - t);
   }

   public void OnSurfaceTextureAvailable(Android.Graphics.SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height)
   {
       //
   }

   public bool OnSurfaceTextureDestroyed(Android.Graphics.SurfaceTexture surface)
   {
       //
       return false;
   }

   public void OnSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(Android.Graphics.SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height)
   {
       //
   }

   public void OnSurfaceTextureUpdated(Android.Graphics.SurfaceTexture surface)
   {
       //
   }

   public Bundle savedInstanceState { get; set; }
}
```

}

and this is is my mapLayout.xaml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#fcfcfc"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center">
<TextView
    android:text="Mapbox test"
    android:textColor="#404040"
    android:textSize="60dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    mapbox:access_token="MY_ACCESS_TOKEN" />
</LinearLayout>
```

however when i run it a get this errors:

```
  05-25 13:56:54.287 E/mono    (16862): Unhandled Exception:
    05-25 13:56:54.287 E/mono    (16862): Android.Views.InflateException: Binary      XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView ---> Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView ---> Java.Lang.Reflect.InvocationTargetException: Exception of type 'Java.Lang.Reflect.InvocationTargetException' was thrown. ---> Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.widgets.UserLocationView ---> Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.widgets.UserLocationView ---> Java.Lang.Reflect.InvocationTargetException: Exception of type 'Java.Lang.Reflect.InvocationTargetException' was thrown. ---> Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
05-25 13:56:54.287 E/mono    (16862): 
05-25 13:56:54.287 E/mono    (16862):   --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
05-25 13:56:54.287 E/mono    (16862): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
05-25 13:56:54.287 E/mono    (16862):   at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
05-25 13:56:54.287 E/mono    (16862):   at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
05-25 13:56:54.287 E/mono    (16862):   at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.<init>(LocationManager.java:227)
05-25 13:56:54.287 E/mono    (16862):   at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.<init>(LocationManager.java:227)
05-25 13:56:54.287 E/mono    (16862):   at android.location.LocationManager.wrapListener(LocationManager.java:864)
05-25 13:56:54.287 E/mono    (16862):   at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:877)
05-25 13:56:54.287 E/mono    (16862):   at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:464)
05-25 13:56:54.287 E/mono    (16862):   at com.mapzen.android.lost.internal.FusionEngine.enablePassive(FusionEngine.java:118)
05-25 13:56:54.287 E/mono    (16862):   at com.mapzen.android.lost.internal.FusionEngine.enable(FusionEngine.java:82)
05-25 13:56:54.287 E/mono    (16862):   at com.mapzen.android.lost.internal.LocationEngine.setRequest(LocationEngine.java:36)
05-25 13:56:54.287 E/mono    (16862):   at com.mapzen.android.lost.internal.FusedLocationProviderApiImpl.requestLocationUpdates(FusedLocationProviderApiImpl.java:38)
05-25 13:56:54.287 E/mono    (16862):   at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.location.LocationServices.toggleGPS(LocationServices.java:104)
05-25 13:56:54.287 E/mono    (16862):   at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.widgets.UserLocationView.toggleGps(UserLocationView.java:378)
05-25 13:56:54.287 E/mono    (16862):   at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.widgets.UserLocationView.setEnabled(UserLocationView.java:251)
05-25 13:56:54.287 E/mono    (16862):   at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.widgets.UserLocationView.initialize(UserLocationView.java:119)
05-25 13:56:54.287 E/mono    (16862):   at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.widgets.UserLocationView.<init>(UserLocationView.java:109)
05-25 13:56:54.287 E/mono    (16862):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
05-25 13:56:54.287 E/mono    (16862):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
05-25 13:56:54.287 E/mono    (16862):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
05-25 13:56:54.287 E/mono    (16862):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
05-25 13:56:54.287 E/mono    (16862):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
05-25 13:56:54.287 E/mono    (16862):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
05-25 13:56:54.287 E/mono    (16862):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
05-25 13:56:54.287 E/mono    (16862):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
05-25 13:56:54.287 E/mono    (16862):   at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView.initialize(MapView.java:179)
05-25 13:56:54.287 E/mono    (16862):   at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:158)
05-25 13:56:54.287 E/mono    (16862):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
05-25 13:56:54.287 E/mono    (16862):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
05-25 13:56:54.287 E/mono    (16862):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
05-25 13:56:54.287 E/mono    (16862):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
05-25 13:56:54.287 E/mono    (16862):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
05-25 13:56:54.287 E/mono    (16862):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
05-25 13:56:54.287 E/mono    (16862):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
05-25 13:56:54.287 E/mono    (16862):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
05-25 13:56:54.287 E/mono    (16862): 
05-25 13:56:54.287 E/mono    (16862):   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
05-25 13:56:54.287 E/mono    (16862): 
05-25 13:56:54.287 E/mono    (16862):   --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
05-25 13:56:54.287 E/mono    (16862): java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-25 13:56:54.287 E/mono    (16862):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
05-25 13:56:54.287 E/mono    (16862):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
05-25 13:56:54.287 E/mono    (16862):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
05-25 13:56:54.287 E/mono    (16862):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704
05-25 13:56:54.291 D/OpenGLRenderer(16862): Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
referenceTable GDEF length=814 1
referenceTable GSUB length=11364 1
referenceTable GPOS length=47302 1
```

i have researched an i know the erorr "Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()" is related to code not being run on the UI thread, but it also says it fails to find the mapbox widget.

The example on mapbox xamarin documentation refers to when the map is being  used inside an activitie but here i am creating it in runtime as part of the custom renderer so i am not sure about how to implement de onCreate() onPause() onDestroy()..etc functions.

so what and i missing or maybe i am doing this all wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.widgets.UserLocationView ---> Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Try moving the your **view inflation** inside the main thread delegate:

```
private async void SetupUserInterface()
{
   var activity = this.Context as Activity;
   Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async() =>
   {
       view = activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.mapLayout, this, false);
       // instanciando el mapa
       map = FindViewById<MapView>(Resource.Id.mapView);
       map.StyleUrl = Mapbox.Constants.Style.Emerald;
       var mapboxMap = await map.GetMapAsync();
       var position = new CameraPosition.Builder()
       .Target(new LatLng(41.885, -87.679))
       .Zoom(11)
       .Build();
       mapboxMap.AnimateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.NewCameraPosition(position), 2500);
   });
}
```